# Portaudio - Unable to play audio file

Tags: c++, portaudio

I'm trying to implement a very simple API for audio playback using `portaudio`. I have minimal amount of code needed to play the audio file but I am not getting any errors and/or audio output.

Here is the code,

```cpp
    AudioStream::AudioStream()
    {
        PaError err = Pa_Initialize();

        if (err != paNoError)
            SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }

    AudioStream::~AudioStream()
    {
        PaError err = Pa_Terminate();

        if (err != paNoError)
            SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }

    int AudioStream::Callback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer,
                              unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                              const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                              PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                              void* userData)
    {
        // Prevent warnings
        (void)inputBuffer;
        (void)timeInfo;
        (void)statusFlags;

        // an AudioFile gets passed as userData
        AudioFile* file = (AudioFile*)userData;
        float* out = (float*)outputBuffer;

        sf_seek(file->file, file->readHead, SF_SEEK_SET);

        auto data = std::make_unique<float[]>(framesPerBuffer * file->info.channels);
        file->count = sf_read_float(file->file, data.get(), framesPerBuffer * file->info.channels);

        for (int i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer * file->info.channels; i++)
            *out++ = data[i];

        file->readHead += file->buffer_size;

        if (file->count > 0)
            return paContinue;
        else
            return paComplete;
    }

    AudioFile AudioStream::Load(const char* path)
    {
        AudioFile file;

        std::memset(&file.info, 0, sizeof(file.info));
        file.file = sf_open(path, SFM_READ, &file.info);

        return file;
    }

    bool AudioStream::Play(AudioFile* file)
    {
        m_OutputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
        m_OutputParameters.channelCount = file->info.channels;
        m_OutputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
        m_OutputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(m_OutputParameters.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
        m_OutputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = nullptr;

        // Check if m_OutputParameters work
        PaError err = Pa_IsFormatSupported(nullptr, &m_OutputParameters, file->info.samplerate);

        if (err != paFormatIsSupported)
        {
            SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
            return false;
        }

        err = Pa_OpenStream(&m_pStream,
                            nullptr,
                            &m_OutputParameters,
                            file->info.samplerate,
                            file->buffer_size,
                            paClipOff,
                            &AudioStream::Callback,
                            file);

        if (err != paNoError)
        {
            SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
            return false;
        }

        if (m_pStream)
        {
            err = Pa_StartStream(m_pStream);

            if (err != paNoError)
            {
                SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
                return false;
            }

            SH_LOG_DEBUG("Waiting for playback to finish..");

            while (IsStreamActive())    // <----- this works, but the application freezes until this ends
                Pa_Sleep(500);

            Stop();

            if (IsStreamStopped())
            {
                SH_LOG_DEBUG("Stream stopped..");

                err = Pa_CloseStream(m_pStream);

                if (err != paNoError)
                {
                    SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            SH_LOG_DEBUG("Done..");
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool AudioStream::Stop()
    {
        PaError err = Pa_StopStream(m_pStream);

        if (err != paNoError)
        {
            SH_LOG_ERROR("PAError: {}", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    bool AudioStream::IsStreamStopped()
    {
        if (Pa_IsStreamStopped(m_pStream))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I noticed that if I add a print statement in the `while` loop I do get audio output.

```cpp
        // Wait until file finishes playing
        while (file->count > 0) { SH_LOG_DEBUG(""); }
```

Why doesn't it play with a print statement or anything in while loop? Do I have to have something in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two flaws that I can see.

One is using what looks like a class method as the callback to PulseAudio.  Since PA is a C API, it expects a C function pointer here.  It won't call that function with the `this` pointer set, so you can't have a class method here.  But maybe `AudioStream::Callback` is `static`?  That will work.

Two is that you need to consider that the callback is called in another thread.  The compiler does not take that into account when it optimizes the code.  As far as it knows, there is nothing in your empty while loop that could possibly change the value of `file->count`.

Once you call the debug function, it brings in enough code, some probably in libraries that are already compiled, that the compiler can't be sure nothing has modified `file->count`.  Maybe `SH_LOG_DEBUG()` calls `prinf()` and then `printf()` calls `AudioStream::Load()`?  Of course it doesn't, but if the compiler doesn't see the code of `printf()` because it's already in a library, and your `AudioStream` object is global, then it's possible.  So it actually works like you want.

But even when it works, it's really bad.  Because the thread is sitting there busy waiting for the count to stop, hogging the/a CPU.  It should block and sleep, then get notified when the playback finishes.

If you want to pass information between threads in a way that works, and also block instead of busy waiting too, look into the [C++ concurrency support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).  The C++20 `std::latch` and `std::barrier` would work well here.  Or use a C++11 `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: Yes the `AudioStream::Callback` is a `static` member method. I have updated the code in my original post. I have never worked with `threading`, I saw some example code and documentation online. I tried to make a thread for the `while` loop using `lambdas`. It works but my application freezes until the loop ends and I am not sure how do I make application not freeze. Do I have to like make my entire application on a thread. I am currently using `C++ 17` but can upgrade to 20.

Comment: `AudioStream::Play()` waits until the audio has finished.  So, how could one call Play() and then before that returns, continue and do other things?  You would need to make new thread, then have it call Play().  Or change Play() so that it just starts the stream and does not wait.  Then check if it is active and stop it with another method, which your app will have to figure out when to call.

Comment: Okay so I tried to create a thread for calling the `Play()`, but the application still freezes. `std::thread thread(&SampleHive::Audio::AudioStream::Play, audioStream, &audioFile);  if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();`. `audioStream` is the local object of the `AudioStream` class and `audioFile` is the argument `Play()` takes. Is this the correct way for creating threads, or am I doing something wrong? I also tried using `std::async` but that didn't help either. `std::async(std::launch::async, SampleHive::Audio::AudioStream::Play, audioStream, &audioFile);` I am using `ImGui` for the UI.

Comment: If you join the thread immediately after creating it, then your code still waits for the audio to finish before continuing.  Because it is waiting for the thread to finish.  Why don't you try having `Play()` not wait.  Just start and then don't stop the stream.

Comment: If I just start the stream and remove the `while` loop and `Pa_StopStream` I don't get any audio output. I tried this with and without thread.

Comment: Make sure your AudioStream object continues to exist, as it will terminate pulseaudio when the destructor runs.

Comment: Yes, I created `AudioStream` object on the heap rather than the stack, I get audio output now. I guess I can consider this solved. Now I need to figure out a way to inform the app that the stream has stopped so it needs to close the stream and do some cleanup. Perhaps I need some kind of signaling or event system for this.